# Writing integration test for asynchronous code in React application with Context and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

So, in useEffect I am fetching an object from the API then I am dispatching response data to the Context reducer and then updating the state. It looks something like this:

```
export const fetchItem = (id) => request({url: `/items/${id}`, method: 'get'});
```

...

```
const {dispatch, singleItem} = useProvider();
    
useEffect(() => {
        const id = getItemIdFromUrl(props);
        fetchItem(id).then((response) => {
          dispatch(action(response.data.data));
        });
      }, [props, dispatch]);
```

I would like to write a good integration test for this. I am using react-testing-library with Jest. I am trying to mock the return value of the fetchItem function and then to check if everything is rendered correctly but constantly getting this warning:

```
act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
```

Any chance to do this correctly?

This is how the request method looks like:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import humps from 'humps';
import {getItem} from './localStorage';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
});

api.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => humps.camelizeKeys(response),
  (error) => Promise.reject(error.response),
);

api.interceptors.request.use(
  (request) => {
    request.data = humps.decamelizeKeys(request.data);
    return request;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error.request),
);

export default function request({url, method, headers = {}, data}) {
  try {
    const token = getItem('token');

    headers.Authorization = token;

    return api({method, url, headers, data});
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.status === 500) {
      console.log('HANDLE ERROR: ', error);
    }

    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe or paste some code on how are you doing the request? Using `fetch`? `Request`? What do you want to render?

Comment: Could you also show the code for your current test?

Comment: Idea was to mock return value of a fetchItem so that the test would cover dispatch, action and reducer from the context. Then to check if everything is rendered correctly in the child component. This was too ambitious apparently.